# Duplicating data but moving FK's and PK's to the new data

Tags: mysql, sql

We're wanting to setup multiple "demo organizations" with large amounts of pre-filled data already existing in our database, **what is the best pattern / method of doing this?**

NOTE: We have several FK's/PK's that will need to be updated, for example, let's say the "base" organization id is 1, we will need to update all the duplicated data with the organization id of 2, not 1 anymore.

My idea of performing this operation is to create a `tmp` table, copy data across and update the data and copy back to the live table, but I'm unsure of how to keep key integrity (eg, each organization has different user_types that are linked to each organization, so every reference to each of the FK's need to be updated as well)

NOTE 2: The server has PHP/Bash scripting available, runs on Linux, if you have a solution that involves external services/languages.

NOTE 3: Some of the tables will have over 1 million rows to duplicate

Comment: why not write a stored procedure that creates a new  demo organization from your "base organization"?

Comment: I've got no real experience using stored procedures, but I'll read into it

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution, but I'm not particularly happy with it.

Theory:

> The theory is as I described in the question, copy the original
>   organization into a temporary table, update it, then copy back across
>   modified. How to solve the FK/PK consistency issue? Get the last used
>   ID of each table you wish to copy across and store it as a user
>   variable called table_name_os, make sure you add +1 to it. We then
>   update all the updated id's as their current value+table_name_os.

Implementation:

```
# Allow unsafe UPDATE/DELETE operations - required on some hosts
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

# User Config
SET @sub_domain='demo.hippos';
SET @org_name='Hungry_Hippos';

# AUTO CONFIG 
SET @org_id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM organisation)+1;
SET @team_id_os=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM team)+1;

### - For each table you want to write, copy this boiler plate - ###
# Organisation 
# Create Temp Table And Move Data To It 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_organisation;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_organisation SELECT * FROM organisation WHERE id=1;
UPDATE temp_organisation SET id=@org_id,name=@org_name,subdomain=@sub_domain; 
# Move Content Back Into Main
INSERT INTO organisation SELECT * FROM temp_organisation;
DROP TABLE temp_organisation;

# Teams 
# Create Temp Table And Move Data To It 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_team;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_team  SELECT * FROM team WHERE organisation_id=1;
UPDATE temp_team SET id=id+@team_id_os,organisation_id=@org_id,team_leader_id=null,manager_id=null; 
# Move Content Back Into Main
INSERT INTO team SELECT * FROM temp_team;
DROP TABLE temp_team;
```

FAQ:

Q: Is this the best solution?
A: Probably not

Q: Can this be stored inside a procedure?
A: Probably, but I've never really used them

Q: Did this work for you?
A: Yes.